# Conditional Statement Not Working

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, lubridate

I want to apply the following conditional statement:

"If the system day is 1, then extract the row in the dataframe containing a 1 in the DAY column, if it is not then just print out the full dataframe."

I thought I had it right but it is only spitting out the date rather than the whole row.

Here is my sample code:

```
library(lubridate)
today <- Sys.Date()
day<-format(today, format="%d")
day <-as.numeric(day)
day

[1] 1

DATE <- as.Date(c('2016-10-31', '2016-11-01','2016-11-02','2016-11-03'))
Revenue <- c(1000,2000,3000,4000)
Count <- c(21000, 23400, 26800,5000)
Price<- c(5.00, 6.00, 6.75, 2.34)
df<-data.frame(DATE, Revenue, Count, Price)

df

        DATE Revenue Count Price
1 2016-10-31    1000 21000  5.00
2 2016-11-01    2000 23400  6.00
3 2016-11-02    3000 26800  6.75
4 2016-11-03    4000  5000  2.34    

df<-data.frame(DATE, Revenue, Count, Price)
df$DAY<-day(df$DATE)
test<-as.data.frame(df)
test$SysDay<-day  

        DATE Revenue Count Price DAY SysDay
1 2016-10-31    1000 21000  5.00  31      1
2 2016-11-01    2000 23400  6.00   1      1
3 2016-11-02    3000 26800  6.75   2      1
4 2016-11-03    4000  5000  2.34   3      1
```

I tried this ifelse statement and to extract the row

```
ifelse(min(test$SysDay)==1, subset(test, DAY == 1 ), test)
```

It is giving me this result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "2016-11-01"
```

If True, I want this result:

```
        DATE Revenue Count Price DAY SysDay
2 2016-11-01    2000 23400     6   1      1
```

If False, I want this result:

```
        DATE Revenue Count Price DAY SysDay
1 2016-10-31    1000 21000  5.00  31      1
2 2016-11-01    2000 23400  6.00   1      1
3 2016-11-02    3000 26800  6.75   2      1
4 2016-11-03    4000  5000  2.34   3      1
```

Comment: `?ifelse` returns a value with the same shape as `test`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
if (min(test$SysDay)==1) { subset(test, DAY == 1 ) } else { test }
```

`ifelse` is coercing `subset(test, DAY == 1 )` to a `list` and only returning the first element because `min(test$SysDay)==1` is a logical vector of length 1.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I will give you credit for this answer in a couple min once it allows me to!